# Unable to use BLANKSASNULL Data conversion parameter in write_dynamic_frame.from_catalog while moving data to Redshift table

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark-sql, amazon-redshift, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

Previously, To move data to Redshift table we used **"Copy"** Command which has the functionality of  Data Conversion parameters like **BLANKSASNULL and EMPTYASNULL**.

**As our data contains both "Empty Strings" and "Null" values, We used to convert both to Null while  moving to Redshift Table.**  as shown below.
Example code :

```
COPY Database.Table 
FROM 's3:/folder/file.csv' 
IAM_ROLE 'arn:aws:iam::0000000:role/RedshiftCopyUnload'
DELIMITER ',' ESCAPE
REMOVEQUOTES
ACCEPTINVCHARS
EMPTYASNULL
BLANKSASNULL
NULL AS 'NULL'
DATEFORMAT 'auto';
```

Now, We had to use **write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf** method, we are trying to replicate the same(copy command data conversion parameters like **BLANKSASNULL and EMPTYASNULL), But we are unable to find the exact reference.

```
# Save data to Redshift
redshift_save_options = {
    "dbtable": "Database." + TableName,
    "database": "Schema"
}

from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
x = DynamicFrame.fromDF(input_data, glueContext, "dfx")

glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf(
    frame = x, 
    catalog_connection = "Regshift-glue-connection", 
    connection_options = redshift_save_options, 
    redshift_tmp_dir = "s3:/project/RedshiftTempDirectory/")
```

Can someone help me in solving this.

**Any suggestion is appreciated . Thankyou**

Answer (score 0):

To replicate the functionality of `BLANKSASNULL` and `EMPTYASNULL`, replace blank and empty columns in the `DataFrame` (i.e. `input_data`) prior to converting it to a `DynamicFrame`.

Example:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when

# replace empty strings values
# calling strip() handles "blank" strings (i.e. handles new line characters, etc)
input_data = input_data.select(
    [
        when(col(c).strip() == "", None).otherwise(col(c)).alias(c) for c in input_data.columns
    ]
)

x = DynamicFrame.fromDF(input_data, glueContext, "dfx")
```

References:

1. [PySpark Replace Empty Value With None/null on DataFrame](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-replace-empty-value-with-none-on-dataframe/)